# How to finish Thread_Square first then Thread_Cube

Tags: java, multithreading

Anyone can help me..
How to get output like this

---

Square Number

Insert Number to get Value of Square: 2

Square of number 2 is 4

Cube Number

Insert Number to get Value of Square: 3

Square of number 3 is 27

---

now I get output like this

---

Square Number

Insert Number to get Value of Square: Square Cube

Insert Number to get Value of Cube: 2

Square of number 2 is 4

3

Cube of number 3 is 27

---

here my coding

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;


    class Thread_Square extends Thread{

     private int sumSquare;

     public void Thread_Square(){

             BufferedReader square = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             System.out.println("Square Number");
             System.out.print("Insert Number to get Value of Square: ");

             String inputSquare = null;
             try {
                 inputSquare = square.readLine();
             } catch (IOException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(Thread_Square.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
             int numSquare = Integer.parseInt(inputSquare);

             sumSquare=numSquare*numSquare;

             System.out.println("Square of number " +numSquare +" is " +sumSquare);


      }
         public void run()
        {

            Thread_Square();


        }
    }

    class Thread_Cube extends Thread{

       public void Thread_Cube(){
          int sumCube;
             BufferedReader Cube = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Square Cube");
             System.out.print("Insert Number to get Value of Cube: ");

             String inputCube = null;
             try {
                 inputCube = Cube.readLine();
             } catch (IOException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(Thread_Square.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
             int numCube = Integer.parseInt(inputCube);

             sumCube=numCube*numCube*numCube;

             System.out.println("Cube of number " +numCube +" is " +sumCube);

    }

        public void run()
        {
              Thread_Cube();


        }
    }

    class Thread_Question1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            Thread_Square obj1 = new Thread_Square();
            obj1.start();


           Thread_Cube obj2 = new Thread_Cube();
            obj2.start();


        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand this probably is some kind of practice to get used to threads and synchronization. But the use case does miss the whole point, why threads are used: To implement **independent** flows of program logic. Having two threads doing some task in serial order is contradicting that, because then you don't need threads at all (at least not for that task). You would just perform the tasks in the desired order, in one thread, neatly one after another. Having threads doing the task implies, that you don't care about the order in which the results arrive.

Comment: @JensG I get task from my lecturer. Write a program that has two threads.One threads should calculate the square of a number while the other thread should calculate the cube of another number. Maybe I think I did mistake in use of threads.And maybe I don't understands about threads.I spent also 6 hours to solve this. I'm student. I think I must study lot about threads and java. Thanks for advices.

Comment: So the original specification did not say anything about the expected order and you added that part?

Comment: @JensG yes I added that part. It didn't say anything. Actually this is exercise for my subject. Web programming. Full question is " Write a program that has two threads.One threads should calculate the square of a number while the other thread should calculate the cube of another number. Maybe I think I did mistake in use of threads.Display the square and cube of the numbers"

Comment: I'd guess the problem lies somewhere else: By printing the values onto console your threads may conflict, because the console is a global/shared resource. I'm not into the Java details, but chances are that the output becomes garbled when two threads are printing onto the same console at the same time. Two solutions: (1) send the results back to the main thread and let him print everything, or (2) synchronize access to the console by some kind of synchronization object. I recommend to implement both (1) and (2) as exercises, to grasp the concepts of thread interaction and synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two concurrent thread that running in same time and parallel. for the first output, you need to have *one thread* with that flow or force the second thread to start after finishing the first one. see this:

```
 Thread_Square obj1 = new Thread_Square();
 obj1.start();

 obj1.join();

 Thread_Cube obj2 = new Thread_Cube();
 obj2.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

wait to first thread finishes using `join()` :

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            MultiThread obj1 = new MultiThread();
            obj1.start();
            obj1.join ();

           ThreadCube obj2 = new ThreadCube();
            obj2.start();



        }
```